# Native extension error installing JSON gem

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, native, ruby-2.1

I've set up the Brightbox Ruby 2.1.0 apt package and encountering a native compilation error installing `json` package.

```
$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'

Fetching: json-1.8.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I've installed `ruby2.0-dev` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/brightbox/deb-ruby2.0/issues/1), but it puts the headers in a different folder (/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby, and copying them to /usr/lib/ruby/include didn't help). Any idea how to install this gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine you'll need to install the ruby2.1-dev package, rather than ruby2.0-dev, if you're using Ruby 2.1. I've not used the Brightbox packages though, so I'm only guessing I'm afraid.

Comment: Doesn't exist unfortunately

Comment: @Jam This would be more appropriate for a comment vs an answer.

Comment: Actually I looked at this again and it does exist, and fixes the issues. Almost sure I tried it before and got an error (maybe it was on a machine lacking the brightbox repo config). Anyway it's working now.